# How can i use mailgun to send mails and godaddy webmail to receive emails?

Tags: email, server, smtp

I am working on a website in which i need fast email delivery so that i am using mailgun to send my mails.
But, there is a problem, when any user want to reply my mail then i can't to see or reposed to their mails.

So, i want to use godaddy Professional webmail to receive and responed to user emails.

```
Mailgun required DNS:-
SPF-- mydomain.com
DKIM--  mx._domainkey.mydomain.com
MX--  mydomain.com
CNAME--   email.mydomain.com

Godaddy Professional webmail required DNS:-
SPF
DKIM
CNAME
MX
```

Please, tell me how can i do this.